# how to handle multiple dropdown change on single button in angular,typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular9

I have mutiple dropdowns in my template (ngFor generates them ) along with save and cancel button. when user changes any dropdown value or multiple dropdown values, i need to enable save (if selected value does not match with default value) and onclick of save i need to update these changed value using API call.

I can update single dropdown changed value. but i need to handle it for multiple dropdowns on one save button, any idea how to do it?

my template looks like this,

```
<tr *ngFor="let expense of expenses">
  <td>{{expense.Category + expense.SubCategory}}</td>
  <td>
    <select>
    <option *ngFor="let category of CategoryMapping" [selected]="category.CategoryName == expense?.mappedCategory">
    {{ category.CategoryName }}
    </option>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try to create form in angular way. check this: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Answer (score 0):

You can us onChange event hook for your requirement. Whenever user selects some thing in the drop down you can trigger your function. Observe the value we get in console log of onChange event you can understand.

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
<option *ngFor="let i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange(deviceValue) {
console.log(deviceValue);
}
```

Angular Life cycle hook ngOnChanges can be used for your problem here is the reference link [Angular NgonChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)
This will have many useful properties like prev value of changed value etc where you can add some logic by triggering a function.

Comment: yes. but as you noticed, there are multiple selects in template (cause of *ngFor). i need to call API only once to send updated values for all dropdowns